# android uiautomatorviewer captures different screen shots for the same page at different times

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

we are using uiautomator to test one of our apps, which has facebook login support. weird enough, sometimes uiautomator fails/stops on the facebook page that asks to confirm facebook login after userid/password input, this page is the page that appears after uiautomator inputs our facebook userid and password.

we use uiautomatorviewer to capture the screen shot, and compare to the happy case that uiautomator makes it pass. it turns out whenever uiautomator fails/stops, the captured .uix file by uiautomatorviewer is incomplete, meaning some critical button (such as the big blue "OK" button) is not captured in the .uix file. that explains why uiautomator can't find the button therefore can't tap it to proceed. but the question is how this happens?

this happens to us from time to time, on a pretty consistent base.

is that a bug on uiautomator, or facebook login with uiautomator? this makes me double uiautomator's credibility.

[image: Valid XHTML].

Comment: Can you also share the faulty screen shot?

Comment: both the faulty screen shot and the good one are same from the perspective of image itself. they are probably identical from eyeballing

what's different is those associated .uix files. the good one has much more widgets captured therefore you can select the blue "OK" button; however the faulty has much less widgets captured and you can NOT select the blue "OK" button

Comment: sorry neither file is too large to include here

Comment: for example in this case if i run uiautomator runtest then exception thrown back:

 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
 Error in testDemo:
  com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.Button, CONTAINS_DESCRIPTION=OK]

        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow(UiObject.java:432)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow(UiObject.java:410)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Screenshot` feature needs all `UI objects` on the screen to be recognizable by `UI Automator`.. I believe it must be problem with the `application` itself..

Comment: the thing is that if .uix does not capture all widgets, when you select some particular area in the .png uiautomatorviewer won't highlight the widget text, properties, etc.